# Is it possible to write to multiple indexes with an ElasticSearch alias?

Tags: elasticsearch

The [ElasticSearch Docs](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html) reads:

> An alias can also be mapped to more than one index, and when specifying it, the alias will automatically expand to the aliases indices.

But when I try to add an alias to 2 indices and write to both, neither seem to get updated with the document. If I remove one of the aliases, it will write correctly to the alias that still exists.

Fails with multiple write aliases:

```
$ curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_aliases'
```

result:

```
{
  "dev_01": {
    "aliases": {
      "dev_read": {},
      "dev_write": {}
    }
  },
  "dev": {
    "aliases": {
      "dev_write": {}
    }
  }
}
```

Works with single alias:

```
$ curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_aliases'
```

result:

```
{
  "dev_01": {
    "aliases": {
      "dev_read": {},
      "dev_write": {}
    }
  },
  "dev": {
    "aliases": {}
  }
}
```

Does elasticsearch support writing to multiple indices? Are aliases Read-Only if pointed at multiple indices?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

the answer is No

So it appears I should have triaged this a beep deeper, but the response my client gets from es is:

> ElasticSearchIllegalArgumentException[Alias [dev_write] has more than one indices associated with it [[dev_01, dev]], can't execute a single index op

Just wish [the docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.10/indices-aliases.html) were a little more explicit up front, as they confused me a bit

At first seems to imply you can:

> The index aliases API allow to alias an index with a name, with **all** APIs automatically converting the alias name to the actual index name. An alias can also be mapped to more than one index...
>
> Associating an alias with more than one index are simply several add actions...

Further down the page lets you know you can not:

> It is an error to index to an alias which points to more than one index.

Comment: Correct, the reason for the answer is: how can elasticsearch know which index is supposed to hold that new document if the alias points to multiple indices? Indexing is a single index operation, like any write operation, thus it needs to execute on a specific index.

Comment: @javanna: I would rather say: because it is not implemented. I could think of a few ways to specify where and how to write to.

Comment: @soulmerge sure it would be possible by specifying where to write to, which would make it less useful to use the alias though. There is a reason if it's not supported. If you have better ideas though feedback is more than welcome!

Comment: @soulmerge we can publicly discuss this, just open an issue at http://www.github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/issues or send a message to our mailing list.

Comment: The strange thing is I'm virtually certain this used to work on early versions of ElasticSearch.  I used to rely on the behaviour so the incremental updates could flow to two indexes while a full index rebuild was in progress.

Comment: I think having single alias for multiple index is a good choice where two indexes are highly correlated in their domain but need a logical separation because of data constraints. We can specify specific update instructions but still want single alias to work

Comment: Issue about adding this behavior https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/68003