# Is rolling indices possible with an 'atomic alias move' for the curator from ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-curator

In the old times I have written and used my own plugin '[rollindex](https://github.com/karussell/elasticsearch-rollindex)' to handle the 'rolling' of e.g. log data. Then I've seen curator and thought that this is a good replacement as it can add and remove aliases. But how can I move aliases atomically?

According to [the docs](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/curator/current/alias.html) I don't think that this is possible. The docs suggest a pattern where I add two indices to one alias and then remove the older index from the alias. But this means for a small time that all writes will fail due to [an ElasticSearch limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19665989/194609). My rollindex plugin has an atomic move (adding+removing at the same time) where this won't happen.

**How would I do this with the curator?**

Comment: what do you mean by "moving the alias"? would you care to elaborate?

Comment: It is indeed more 'moving the index'. And I just mean adding the new index and removing the old index from an alias **in one request** like I do here: https://github.com/karussell/elasticsearch-rollindex/blob/master/src/main/java/com/pannous/es/rollindex/RollAction.java#L281

Comment: curator doesn't do that! there is no zero downtime reindexing in elasticsearch

Comment: I do not mean reindexing! I just mean this regarding the alias. And that it is possible you see from the java API that I use there :) now I need to know if that is possible with curator

Comment: but in Java that's not atomic! it does two actions add and remove

Comment: No, it is atomic. Trust me or read the docs ;)

Comment: Search for 'atomic' http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-aliases.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76624/discussion-between-eliasah-and-karussell).

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not implemented. See [this issue](https://github.com/elastic/curator/issues/367)